# Can a cellular automata structure simulates another cellular automata structure?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, space-complexity, cellular-automata

In Elementary Cellular Automata, rules can show one pattern, but i am wondering if there is something where a cellular automata structure can simulate another structure?

Is there a category for this in Cellular Automata?

Answer (score 1):

Any cellular automata that could be classified as a universal Turing machine would be able to do this. The Game of Life is one such cellular automata. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP5-iIeKXE8) is it (rather pointlessly) simulating itself on a larger scale. [Here](http://rendell-attic.org/gol/tm.htm) is a Turing machine implemented in it. This 'category' that you want is probably "cellular automata that qualify as universal Turing machines".
I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394957/why-can-conway-s-game-of-life-be-classified-as-a-universal-machine) question will be of interest to you.

Comment: Welcome! Certainly, any cellular automaton that can simulate a universal Turing machine can simulate other cellular automata. I suppose, though, that it's also possible to have a weaker CA that can simulate other weak CAs, but isn't powerful enough to simulate a universal TM. So the category isn't necessarily just the class of CAs that can simulate universal TMs.